# ajax post request treated differently on IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, post

```
$("#submitbutton").button().click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "mmm.php",
    data:"abc=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
    success:function(data){ alert("success: " +data); },
    error:function(data){ alert("error "+data); },
    statusCode:{
        200:function(){alert("200");},
        304:function(){alert("304");},
        404:function(){alert("404");}},
    isModified:function(){alert("Something was modified");}
});
```

This Post on IE9 is replied correctly. On chrome, It generates error alert with the following:  "error [Object][Object]"

Chrome Console show no error, server replies:

for IE:

> 10.0.0.4 - - [22/Jul/2012:18:00:22 +0300] "GET /development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js HTTP/1.1" 200 11342 "http://xxxx.xxxx.net/first.html" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)"

For Chrome:

> 10.0.0.4 - - [22/Jul/2012:18:08:34 +0300] "GET /development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://xxxx.xxxxxx.net/first.html?" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11"

Any idea why chrome adds a question mark after the 'first.html' and IE don't ? It causes the apache server to return 304 that looks to Chrome as error

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to first fix your jSon that you wish to pass to the server.. it is incorrect currently.. change it to the following and then try.

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "mmm.php",
    data:{abc:"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"},
    success:function(data){ alert("success: " +data); },
    error:function(data){ alert("error "+data); },
    statusCode:{
        200:function(){alert("200");},
        304:function(){alert("304");},
        404:function(){alert("404");}},
    isModified:function(){alert("Something was modified");}
});
```

I also modified your event binding, the `button()` call doesnt seem necessary.

Comment: `data:"abc=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is not a `json object` and you can send data like this `data:"abc=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&more=moredata"`.